# I don't even have the option to run a test with a coverage

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't even have the option to run a test with a coverage
Android studio version 3.6.3

I tried everything:

I tried checking the tab below the JUnit - label test coverage not display

I tried add in gradle buildTypes {
            debug {
                testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
I tried to delete android-studio and installing from scratch and nothing work.

Does someone have a solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, after taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you will even have some rewards), please be sure to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then edit the question with a sample.